# sql query help between two tables

Tags: sql

#### Table 1

```
table1
row 1 
row 2
row 3
```

#### Table 2

```
table2
row 1
```

Want query which show only rows of table1 which is not in table2

#### Result

```
result
row 2
row 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL set operators are your friend:

```
SELECT row FROM table1
EXCEPT
SELECT row FROM table2
```

Or you can use `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT row
FROM table1
WHERE row NOT IN (SELECT row FROM table)
```

These assume that your tables have one column called `row` and that the columns are the same type. You should be able to adapt them to your real tables easily enough though.

Answer (score 1):

```
select table1.col1 from table1
where not exists 
   (select table2.col1 from table2 where table1.col1 = table2.col1)
```